# Prometheus sink metrics servlet not found in azure databricks runtime

Tags: apache-spark, prometheus, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to expose the spark metrics to an external Prometheus server.
Unfortunately Databricks is not having prometheus as sink metrics.

Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.metrics.sing.PrometheusServlet
```

Is there any DBR version which will have prometheus as sink coming in by default ?
Or can we install those libraries using init scripts before we set the sinks metrics to prometheus ?

Init script being used:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat << EOF > /databricks/spark/conf/metrics.properties
*.sink.prometheusServlet.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.PrometheusServlet
*.sink.prometheusServlet.path=/metrics/prometheus
master.sink.prometheusServlet.path=/metrics/master/prometheus
applications.sink.prometheusServlet.path=/metrics/applications/prometheus
EOF
```

After the init script gets executed, the cluster boot up is failing since spark is not able to find the prometheus servlet/library and the initialization of spark context is failing and terminating the cluster.

Comment: what DBR version are you using?

Comment: Tried with both 7.x and 9.x.. both are throwing the same error..

Comment: please show how do you configure it...

Comment: Added the init script and how i am configuring the sink for prometheus